# Will records in a particular match be discarded if the bowler is called for throwing?

Tags: cricket

A Bowler is called for throwing while he took 4 wickets and a hat trick.

Will it be neglected and the records he made in that match are discarded if he is declared throwing?

Answer (score 1):

I am struggling to find a reference but the answer would be no.  The statistics would remain, the logic would be that those must have been legitimate deliveries as the umpire/s did not no ball them.

Looking at the evidence this is supported by Muralis statistics from the match where he was called for throwing.